# Why are references to the in-app billing classes not recognized by Ecliplse?

Tags: android, eclipse, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I am using [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html) to implement in-app billing for an Android app. When I get to the section titled "Binding to IInAppBillingService" they provide a snippet like this:

```
IInAppBillingService mService;

ServiceConnection mServiceConn = new ServiceConnection() {
   @Override
   public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
       mService = null;
   }

   @Override
   public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, 
      IBinder service) {
       mService = IInAppBillingService.Stub.asInterface(service);
   }
};
```

And even though I installed the in-app billing library from my SDK manager, it doesn't seem to be recognizing the classes used in this snippet.

Am I maybe using a tutorial that isn't the most clear? Is there a better tutorial? This one seems to gloss over a few important details like where to get the actual class implementation for the referenced classes in that code.

Or do I just not have the libraries correctly configured?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've copied `<sdk>/extras/google/play_billing/IInAppBillingService.aidl` file to your Eclipse project's `src/com/android/vending/billing` package. Then rebuild the project. Once you've done this, Eclipse will generate `IInAppBillingService.java` class and put it into `gen` folder of your project. Don't forget to import that java class and everything must compile.